# Update to Flyway metadata table has script name inserted with First letter clipped

Tags: flyway

I have a custom version of Flyway with MemSQL support added on top of flyway 4.0.3.

I am getting a weird issue of first letter getting clipped when inserting to flyway metadata table in MemSQL. The flyway.sqlMigrationPrefix is set as Schema and the migration files are picked up correctly and executed without any issues. But the entry in metadata table has this issue.

Does anyone know any reason why this is happening?

Another issue is when I run the migration directly from the code base this issue does not occur. This occurs from the Flyway jar file I created. For example, "Schema16_6_0_1235__abc_SCHEMA.sql" is the actual name, but the entry in metadata table is "chema16_6_0_1235__abc_SCHEMA.sql".

Answer (score 0):

Hard to guess what it might be given you have a home rolled version of Flyway.

All I can suggest is you whip out your debugger, attach during the `migration` phase and put a break point on [`ResolvedMigration#setDescription`](https://github.com/flyway/flyway/blob/master/flyway-core/src/main/java/org/flywaydb/core/internal/resolver/ResolvedMigrationImpl.java) to have a look at the call stack. I presume something will lead you to a method in Flyways [`StringUtils.java`](https://github.com/flyway/flyway/blob/master/flyway-core/src/main/java/org/flywaydb/core/internal/util/StringUtils.java).

Well worth doing as you may surface a bug that is worth reporting and /or contributing a fix for.